# .htaccess rewritecond, multiple matches

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite this URL:

```
http://example.com/no/news/archive/
```

to

```
http://example.com/index.php?lang=no&uri=/news/archive/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
# inside .htaccess for the document root of example.com
RewriteBase /   # good habit; not needed for this absolute rewrite though

# rewrite exact URL
RewriteRule ^index.php\?lang=en&uri=/news/archive/$ /no/news/archive/
```

You might want the matching to be more flexible. What if `lang` isn't there or isn't `en`? Or appears after `uri=/news/archive`? Also, can clients ask for subdirectories under `/news/archive/` and should all such requests go to `/no/news/archive/`?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be flexible. The `lang` should switch between `en` and `no`, the `uri` can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide a lot of information here's what should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/no/news/archive/$ /index.php?lang=en&uri=/news/archive/
```

But this is not very flexible.

Provide more information if you want a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^no(/news/archive/?)$ index.php?lang=en&uri=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```